# How to fix Winforms project that thinks it is a WPF project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have inherited a legacy VB.NET WinForms application. Despite being a WinForms application, in the project properties the Application Type is "WPF Application".

[image]

There is no option to change the Application Type to "Windows Application":

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio 2022, but the original application was built years ago in a previous version. There's some evidence that it may have been decompiled from an exe but I don't know the full history.

Is there any way I can change it to "Windows Application"?

Comment: The Application type is determined by the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` entry in the `.vbproj` file. WinForms doesn't use it. You can comment it out... maybe

Comment: Try opening your project file in a text editor and setting the `OutputType` value as `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>`.

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin The OutputType is of course already WinExe for both WinForms and WPF

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer. If it helps you can accept it so that it can help more people. If it does not work for you, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Based upon @Jimi's comment.*

Using Notepad I commented out the following line from the .vbproj file:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60DC8134-EBA5-43B8-BCC9-BB4BC16C2548};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

The project has the correct type now:

[image]

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people

Answer (score 0):

I created a Winforms program and used Notepad to open the vbproj file.

`<ProjectGuid>{7CA9CE2C-69C5-45F9-A216-5BDD4132EFEA}</ProjectGuid>`

replaced by

`<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}</ProjectTypeGuids>`

At this time, I use Visual Studio to open the Winforms project again, and Visual Studio will recognize the project as a WPF project:

[image]

If your vbproj file contains:

`<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}</ProjectTypeGuids>`

You can annotate it

Comment: NOT REPLACE. `<ProjectGuid>` is the identifier assigned to a Project (its *identity* among other Projects created in the same machine)